# joining across databases with sqlite3 / pysqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, pysqlite

I have two separate database files each with tables with matching primary keys, but different data. I want to pull out rows from one table based on values in the other. In the CLI for `sqlite3`, I would do this like:

```
.open data.db
.open details.db
attach 'data.db' as data;
attach 'details.db' as details;

select details.A.colA from data.A join details.A using ('key') where data.A.colB = 0 and data.A.colC = 1;
```

How can I recreate such a cross-database join using `pysqlite`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can attach additional databases with [`ATTACH DATABASE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html):

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
conn.execute('ATTACH DATABASE details.db AS details')
```

For query purposes, the first database is known as `main`:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''
    select details.A.colA
    from main.A
    join details.A using ('key')
    where main.A.colB = 0 and main.A.colC = 1
    ''')
```